# Cannot save plots in Octave using print()

Tags: plot, png, octave

I'm simply trying to print the current figure in Octave to a `.png` file using the `print()` function. The documentation seems pretty straightforward, but it's not working. I get no error messages, but the files are nowhere to be found. I am doing

```
filename = sprintf('/home/me/Desktop/file_%d.png',n);
print(filename, '-dpng');
```

where `n` is just some loop counter variable. Again, I get no error, but when I check `/home/me/Desktop/`, there are no files. Am I doing this wrong?

Comment: try something simple: `plot(1:10); print("out.png");` do you see out.png in your current working directory (show with `pwd`)

Comment: There is no way anyone can help you with the question as it is, your issue is on the details that you omit. Please provide a [minimal working example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). I'm voting to close as off-topic until then.

Comment: @Andy No I do not, nothing is saved

Comment: @jphollowed: Which graphics_toolkit? Try with fltk, qt, gnuplot. Also try `plot(1:10); print("out.eps");` (which doesn't use ghostscript)

Comment: @Andy I tried fltk and gnuplot, neither work. I don't have qt listed as available. I also tried changing `png` to `eps`, no change :(

Comment: What Octave version on which distribution? Installed via yum/apt-get/aptitude/pacman or compiled from source?

Comment: @Andy version 3.8.1 on Ubuntu 14.04 from apt-get

Answer (score 0):

Octave probably doesn't know where your current figure is or the filename is  bad. Try using this version of print

print (h, filename, options)

with h given for the plot figure handle. Also try printing the filename to console and make sure it is correct

Comment: "h" is the handle of the figure and has nothing to do with a "file". If you omit h it uses `gcf`. If the filename would be wrong he would get an error like "GPL Ghostscript 9.06: **** Could not open the file foo/bar/baz.png "

Comment: @Andy I never said h was the filename. Read my comment, it looks like he is iterating over multiple plots. Gcf gives you the current plot, so if he clicked somewhere it wouldn't work. Giving the figure handle to the plot method is better form.

Comment: Read your answer: "..with h given for the plot filehandle...".

Comment: @andy the simple solution to this would have been to suggest an edit. Clearly I meant figure handle. That symantics, I wasn't talking about a physical file. Most people would understand

Comment: I tried this, it changes nothing, no output of any kind